# Telerik MVC grid Access Data out side the grid binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

In Telerik MVC 3.0 Grid (Razor engine)

How can i access the data after grid binding.
I am using Detailed view tab
using below code.

```
items.Add()
     .Text("Additional Tab")
     .Content(@<text>
    @(Html.Telerik()
          .Grid<Models.PModel>()
          .Name( "Additional_<#= AddressID #>" )
          .DataBinding( dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax()
                                                  .Select( "Action", "Controller", new { ID = "<#= ID #>" } ) )
          .Pageable()
          .Sortable()
          .Columns( columns =>
          {
            columns.Bound( e => e.Name ).Title( "Name" ).Width( 150 );
            columns.Bound( e => e.Email ).Title( "Email" );
            columns.Bound( e => e.Status ).Title( "Prescriber Status" );
            columns.Template( e => e.ID ).ClientTemplate( 
                        Ajax.ActionLink( "Edit", "EditDetails", new { ID = "<#= ID #>", PID = "<#= PID #>" }, 
                        new AjaxOptions
                        {
                            OnSuccess = "LoadAddEditForm",
                            UpdateTargetId = "ShowAddEditFormDialogModel",
                            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                        },
                        new { @class = "button" } ).ToString() );
          } )
         .NoRecordsTemplate( "No additional added for this" )
    )
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add New", "AddEdit", "Controller", 
    new { ID =  "<#= ID #>"},
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnSuccess = "LoadAddEditForm",
        UpdateTargetId = "ShowAddEditFormDialogModel",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    }, 
    new { @class = "button", id="AjaxAddNewButton" })
</text>);
```

**Now the Problem is,, if you notice i have added a Ajax.Action link after the grid binding.**

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add New", "AddEdit", "Controller", 
    new { ID =  "<#= ID #>"},
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnSuccess = "LoadAddEditForm",
        UpdateTargetId = "ShowAddEditFormDialogModel",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    },
    new { @class = "button", id="AjaxAddNewButton" })
```

In this Ajax Link I can get the value of object `new { ID =  "<#= ID #>"}` 
as I am trying to access the **<#= ID #>** after the grid binding, it is not rendering the value.
How can i get this work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would be interested in the answer to this question, though I don't think what you're asking is possible. Since the Ajax.ActionLink is created on the server, it can't be updated on the client with server-side code. You'd have to update the link on the client in Javascript. Or maybe there is some way to bind the route value using MVC..?

Comment: Well we can do this in clinetTemplate. when row is binding, we can assign object values with <#= filedName #>, Only question is how can we do it after grid binding is complete. There is other alternate .toolbar(c=>c.custom().text("Add").Action("action","Controller",new{ID="<#= ID #>"})) But even in this way <#= ID #> doesn't render the value

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

The `<# ID #>` you are using is for a **single row** in your grid. It cannot be used outside the `.Columns()` method. So your column template may work, but if you inspect what is being sent to the Action handling the binding, you will see that the ID parameter literally equals "<# ID #>".

For the ActionLink past the grid, what ID did you want? from which row?